# Basic bash shell scripting on nmon

Tags: linux, shell

I'm having a problem trying to run nmon using my own script where nmon is deployed in the linux environment.

Based on this script, I am required to execute command "test.sh 2 5", with variables represented by value 2 and 5

```
#!/bin/bash
#sh test.sh variable1 variable2
./nmon -f -s$1 -c $2
total=$(( $1 * $2 ))
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Providing $2 snapshots with interval of $1s"
echo -e "Saving into $HOSTNAME. Completing in $total seconds\n\n"
```

However, I am receiving the following output:

```
[osmusr@bssosmappv4001 ~]$ sh nmonscript2.sh 2 4
------------------------------------------------
Providing 4 snapshots with interval of 2s
 secondsnto bssosmappv4001. Completing in 8
```

May I know which part did I missed out? Why is it not displaying the output correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`total` has a carriage return (`0x0D`/`\r`/`^M`) after it. Most likely the script has windows line endings (`\r\n`), and the `\r` is getting tacked onto the total assignment. Run the file through `dos2unix`.